# rails "rake db:migrate" migration partially done and need to be redone from scratch

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database-migration

I'm new to ruby-on-rails and having hard time.

I tried to run
"rake db:migrate" but it was aborted because there was a typo. I typed "users " instead of "users".
So I fixed the rb file in db/migrate directory and tried to run it again only to find migration is already partially proceeded and I cannot redo it over again. It seems like it's a common error by beginner like me and the instructor presented two solution for this: first DROP the table in SQL or second COMMENT OUT the already-run part and run the leftover.

But before I found the trouble-shooting advice, I thought I can just use different file name(*SIGH*) and I changed the 'users' to 'admin_user' and 'admin_user' to 'admin_user2'.
I didn't work, and I dropped the table and did

$ rails generate migration AlterUsers
and
$ rake db:migrate

But it aborted again because it cannot find this file:users.frm.
(I have no idea where .frm files are..)

Thanks a lot.

---------------------------Error Message----------------------------------------

```
$ rake db:migrate
==  AlterUsers: migrating =====================================================
-- rename_table("users", "admin_users")
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Mysql2::Error: Can't find file: './simple_cms_development/users.frm' (errno: 2 - No such file or directory): RENAME TABLE `users` TO `admin_users`/Users/gymmilo/Sites/simple_cms/db/migrate/20130927112013_alter_users.rb:3:in `change'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

---------------------------migration file----------------------------------------

```
class AlterUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    rename_table("users", "admin_users")
    add_column("admin_users", "username", :string, :limit => 25)
    change_column("admin_users", "email", :string, :limit => 100)
    rename_column("admin_users", "password", "hashed_password")
    add_column("admin_users", "salt", :string, :limit => 40)
    puts "*** About to add an index ***"
    add_index("admin_users", "username")
  end
end
```

------------------------------(I already dropped the table once and it turned out like this! Thanks for help. --------

```
mysql> SHOW TABLES;
+----------------------------------+
| Tables_in_simple_cms_development |
+----------------------------------+
| admin_users1                     |
| schema_migrations                |
+----------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE admin_users1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> exit
Bye
$ rake db:migrate
==  AlterUsers: migrating =====================================================
-- rename_table("users", "admin_users")
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Mysql2::Error: Can't find file: './simple_cms_development/users.frm' (errno: 2 - No such file or directory): RENAME TABLE `users` TO `admin_users`/Users/gymmilo/Sites/simple_cms/db/migrate/20130927112013_alter_users.rb:3:in `change'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
$ mysql -u simple_cms -p simple_cms_development
Enter password: 
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 43
Server version: 5.6.13 Source distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> SHOW TABLES;
+----------------------------------+
| Tables_in_simple_cms_development |
+----------------------------------+
| schema_migrations                |
+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> exit
Bye
$ pwd
/Users/gymmilo/Sites/simple_cms
$ rake db:migrate
==  AlterUsers: migrating =====================================================
-- rename_table("users", "admin_users")
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Mysql2::Error: Can't find file: './simple_cms_development/users.frm' (errno: 2 - No such file or directory): RENAME TABLE `users` TO `admin_users`/Users/gymmilo/Sites/simple_cms/db/migrate/20130927112013_alter_users.rb:3:in `change'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

---

Comment: MySQL represents each table in the database with multiple files, one of which has an extension of FRM. The error 2 about users.frm indicates that there isn't a table with the name of "users" in the referenced database. You might want to either drop and recreate your database or use the MySQL command line to connect to your database and see what tables you actually have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reset database back to the original state using the following command and run the migration again.

```
rake db:reset
```

Answer (score 0):

If your database comes from the production database, you can dump it to local computer and run rake db:migrate.

If it is just a test database, run "rake db:reset", and the whole database would be refresh and all migration task would be executed one by one.

Comment: Being grateful and feeling ashamed at the same time, I've got to ask what the difference is between test database and production database.
The commands I ran is..
$ rails generate migration AlterUsers
$ rake db:migrate

Comment: I'm on Lynda.com Ruby and Rails course and I can delete and redo anything if I need to.. Then can I just 'reset'?